# AppPool Identity when running ASP.Net Core under IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

We use service accounts to run IIS App Pools under. Then we use integrated authority in our DB connection strings.

How is this affected by running an ASP.Net core site using IIS as the proxy? Is the App Pool account passed through? Do I have to do something differently in my connection string?

Comment: You can use Process Monitor to learn. Commonly your Kestrel process is launched by IIS worker process, so they run under the same account. ASP.NET Core 2.2 allows you to host Kestrel in worker process, which is even simpler.

Comment: You should have added the actual error message!

Comment: Have you added service account to the Db access list?